# Как сделать 2000 исходящий GET/POST запросов в секунде Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Столкнулся с такой проблемой... Есть скрипт:

```
function requestNotAsync(i) {

    var opts = {hostname: 'site.com', port: 80, path: '/1.psd'}
    var x = http.get(opts, (res) => {

    res.on('data', (chunk) => { 
        x.abort();
    });
})   
x.end();

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

    setInterval(requestNotAsync, 1000, i);      
}
```

Задача простая, создать 200 "потоков", которые бы каждую секунду, обращалась к сайту для скачивания файла, но после получения первого пакета - обрывало соединение. Задача - создать инструмент отладки сервиса, поэтому не удивляйтесь)

Исходный файл размером > 1мб

Смысл в чём, первый пакет приходит размером 16кб, НО скорость интернета подскакивает при этом до 1мб/с (при мониторнге в диспетчере задач), соответственно при 200 потоках, сетевой канал забивается на 100%, хотя при этом пакеты по 16кб, После 20-30 секунд работы валятся ошибки econnreset , socket hang up. Понятно что timeout и прочее. В теории канал должен забивать не более чем на 20-30%, но за счёт того что исходный файл пытается скачаться весь скорость вырастает (как я понимаю). Запросы идут через прокси, прокси отличные.

Не знаю куда копать, что делать, кто посоветует что?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал использовать что-нибудь вроде ab. Но если нужна именно nodejs, попробуйте использовать tcp модуль напрямую. При скачивании файла, насколько я помню, клиент отправляет запросы за заголовком `Range :from :to`. Просто не шлите их и сразу закрывайте коннект.